# passing url of method in controller , in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax call

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#VEGAS").submit(function(){
   var form_data =  $("#VEGAS").serialize();
    var routeUrl = "<?= url('/'); ?> /PUBLIC/vpage";
    $.ajax({
        url: routeUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#msg-text-group').html('successfully added!');
            $('#msg-group').delay(1000).hide('slow');
           }
         });
      return false;
     });
   }); 
 </script>
```

Here is my controller function

```
   public function vegaspage(Request $request) {


    $inputs = Input::except('_token');
    $validator = Validator::make($inputs, Vegas::$vegas_d);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages()->first();
        return Redirect::to('/vegas')->withMessage($messages);
    } else {
        if (Input::get('submit_1')) {
            $group_data = new Vegas();
            $var = "The Venetian";
            $username = Session::get('login');
            $group_data->user_name = $username;
            $group_data->firstname = input::get("firstname");
            $group_data->lastname = input::get("lastname");
            $group_data->email = input::get("email");
            $group_data->phone = input::get("phone");
            $group_data->check_in = input::get("checkin");
            $group_data->check_out = input::get("checkout");
            $group_data->date = input::get("checkboxG4");
            $group_data->hotel_name = $var;
            $group_data->nofguest = input::get("selecter-guest");
            $group_data->nofrooms = input::get("selecter-rooms");
            $group_data->nofbeds = input::get("selecter-beds");
            $group_data->save();
     }
    }
```

here is my route

```
Route::post('/vpage' , array('as' =>'vpage' ,'uses' =>'VegasController@vegaspage'));
```

After giving form and ajax call same id control is coming to ajax call but the give url is not hitting. There is an error in my ajax url please suggest me any solution. ?

Comment: Try removing the space you're putting in the URL: `var routeUrl = "<?= url('/'); ?>/PUBLIC/vpage";`

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:  is comming in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the return false, it stops the DOM propagation, delete the return false and instead use e.preventDefault like so:

```
  $("#VEGAS").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     // continue your ajax request
```

url in the ajax call should simply be exactly what is in your route.

```
   url: '/vpage'
```

Comment: The requested URL /vpage was not found on this server. is coming in this case

Comment: thanks it is working now. Hitting controller function. I have verify the output request. Request parameters are coming in console but no saving in databse

Comment: You have a die; in your controller function. Remove it first

Comment: Can you echo out something after the if Input::get('submit_1') to be sure that's not the issue?

Comment: i think , the submit button value is not coming in the request.  my if condition is totally base on submit button value

Comment: Do you have multiple submit buttons? If not, remove the if statement. If you do, confirm that the name equals submit_1.

Comment: dear i have multiple submits on my form that's why i have if conditions in my controller.

Comment: how can a send the button value along with url ?\

Comment: Is the name of the button equal to submit_1? i.e. the button must have a name attribute of submit_1

Comment: yes, i have checked it twice name are same , what about if send the vlaue of submmited button in ajax call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136955/discussion-between-learner-and-fatimah-sanni).